# How do I set a system wide node version installed via nvm?

Tags: nodejs, update-alternatives

I use `nvm` to manage my `node` versions, but programs that don't start a shell and don't include `~/.nvm/nvm.sh` don't know where to find node.

Intellij for example can start node programms via `package.json` scripts and you can use it in their terminal, but you can't use node programms from `node_modules/.bin` like `flow` from the `flow-bin` package.

Currently I do some manual setup of symlinks like

```
$ dirname `which node`
/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/bin
$ export NODE_PATH="/home/me/.nvm/versions/node/v8.9.0/bin"
$ dirname `which node` | xargs ls 
node npm npx yarn yarnpkg
```

```sh
for c in `ls $NODE_PATH` ; do 
   sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/$c" "$c" "$NODE_PATH/$c" 1100
   sudo update-alternatives --set "$c" "$NODE_PATH/$c"
done
```

Is there a easier way to persist those settings and get rid of dangling old entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the system-wide Node.js version by typing

```
nvm alias default 11.10.0
```

Install the version that you would like:

```
nvm install 11.10.0
```

Set 11.10.0 (or another version) as default:

```
nvm alias default 6.1.0
```

Verify the current version by running `node -v` or `nvm current`

Comment: Hi Parvez, thank you for your answer. Sadly it doesn't help with programs that don't start a shell and don't include ~/.nvm/nvm.sh as described in the answer.

Comment: This worked for me on linum (ubuntu).  It changed the content of the file `~/.nvm/alias/default` to the n.n.n value.

Comment: For this to work, apparently you need to have done `rm \`which node\``. The symbolic link to system wide node takes precedence to the default node.

Comment: This totally fails. I do `nvm alias default 18` then `sudo node --version` and it's 16. Defeats the whole purpose!